# Manual fsck stuck and no progress during disk check

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian, ext4, fsck

I wanted to run an fsck check on my 5TB external hard drive on my raspberry pi.

This is the output:

```
 $ sudo e2fsck -c -v /dev/sda
 e2fsck 1.44.5 (15-Dec-2018)
 Checking for bad blocks (read-only test):   0.46% done, 5:04 elapsed. (0/0/0 errors)
```

There has been zero progress for hours now. The elapsed time is stuck as well. This is actually my second attempt. Before I tried `sudo e2fsck -p -c -v /dev/sda`. This one doesn't give any output, that's why I let it run for a whole week before terminating.

My drive is unmounted, partitionless, and freshly formatted with mkfs.ext4. Output from ps:

```
 $ ps -a
PID TTY          TIME CMD
1075 tty1     00:00:00 bash
8404 pts/1    00:00:00 sudo
8405 pts/1    00:00:04 e2fsck
8446 pts/1    00:00:00 sh
8447 pts/1    00:00:05 badblocks
23605 pts/2    00:00:00 ps
```

I noticed on my first attempt, that it was impossible to send a SIGINT, SIGTERM, or SIGKILL to badblocks.

Why is this?

Comment: A process that can't be killed is typically blocked in a kernel call. I've seen this happening with faulty drives, although not on a Raspi. Do you have the possibility to test your drive on another computer?

Comment: Not easily. I connect remotely. But I had zero issues with the drive in this regard. I was using it until I noticed that cp failed on some files. I suspected some faulty blocks, that's why I wanted to check with fsck in the first place. Is there maybe some other command to check/test if the drive is faulty?